# Set background image to fill entire page

Tags: android, css, background

First of all, I know there is lot of threads about this, but I just cant seem to get it right for this one particular page.

I spent countless hours trying to get this right and I did for most of the pages I have on my website, but this one I just cant get right. So here is what I have now:

```
body, html {
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
```

}

```
body {
background-image: url(../images/image.png);
min-width: 1200px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: cover;
```

}

It works somewhat fine on big screen but on mobile the body does not cover the entire screen (neither does on big screen, but the picture fill entire screen anyways).

I know i can use

```
    background-attachment: fixed;
```

Which seems to be working when I test different resolution in Chrome on windows, but when you actually try it on android it doesn't work since this is not supported there.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

To perfectly "fit" an Image on almost any modern browser, you can use the `background-size` attribute along with the `vw` (view width) and `vh` (view height) Units:

https://jsfiddle.net/op662k7u/

```
#b{
  background-image: url('https://backgroundss.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/rainbow-background-images.jpg');
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
```

or if you just want the height to apply and width to follow it's scale:

```
#b{
  background-image: url('https://backgroundss.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/rainbow-background-images.jpg');
  background-size: auto 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I tried both options but none of it works, I posted screenshot, this is the best i can do

Answer (score -1):

Android do not use px , convert it to dp , search google: px to dp. then set the height, any way height 100% should work no need to min-height